# Glu-less example of drawing a cube?

Tags: c#, c++, opengl, 3d, opentk

I'm trying to get back into OpenGL, but my knowledge and math are rusty now. I used to use C++, but I prefer C# now... trying out OpenTK. Apparently Glu has been deprecated since GL 3.1, so I'm trying to find a Glu-less example of drawing a cube on the screen in either C# or C++ (I can translate it).

The part I'm finding challenging is setting up the viewport/viewing angle/camera/perspective/initializing stuff. I'm okay with clearing the buffer, and laying down points in 3D space, but the other stuff I forget!

In particular, I need replacements for `Glu.Perpsective` and `Glu.LookAt`.

Comment: If you're trying to use core GL 3.1 and greater, what you need is *shaders*. You need a firm understanding of how OpenGL works in a shader-based world. I would suggest one of the [OpenGL 3.0+ tutorials on this page](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Getting_started#Tutorials_and_How_To_Guides)

Comment: Also, read [this](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_transform.html). Formulas and methodology to do all the matrix calculations you need.

Comment: Oh...apparently we're up to 4.1 now?? Or 4.2? Last time I played this we were still in the 2s I think. Might as well use the latest stable version.

Comment: You don't have to care about 4.x unless you need 64bit float and tessellation.

Comment: @stativ: Thanks. Just realized my card doesn't even support it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest taking a look at the http://openglbook.com/ It says it's OpenGL 4, but everything described here (only the basics so far) directly applies to OpenGL 3 too. I think this is the best resource to get quickly started with recent OpenGL versions. Other very good resource is the [Learning Modern 3D Graphics Programming](http://arcsynthesis.org/gltut/), which goes a tad more in-depth.

You must note that the OpenGL 3 and newer disregards the fixed pipeline. You can still use the fixed pipeline using a compatibility profile, but IMO it's better to learn the programmable pipeline. That means no more immediate mode (eg. `glVertex3f` and similar) and display lists. You have to submit your vertex data directly into to the graphics card prior drawing. This is done using buffer objects, which is nothing but an array of vertex data. Then you have to submit a GLSL program which will process these data, such as applying modelview and projection matrices (even when you don't need fancy shader stuff).

Last but not least the current OpenGL versions doesn't implement matrix operations and lighting (again unless using compatibility profile). You need to create all the matrices on your own, but since it's a tedious work I suggest using an external library.

This all may sound frightening and frankly, I found it more difficult to learn the programmable pipeline than the fixed pipeline. However it gives you much more flexibility.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain some of the differences! I was just looking at an OpenGL 3 example, and they were doing exactly that...creating a "VAO" and "Shader Program"...new concepts to me. I guess I have to do some reading before I can jump in.

Comment: I was a little sceptical after reading the first chapter of the OpenGL book...seemed like really trivial stuff that didn't need so much detail to explain, but I'm glad they took the time to go into detail in the later chapters. Nice refresher on linear algebra!

Answer (score 1):

OpenTK has it's own math classes, including a 4x4 matrix - `Matrix4`. It includes both orthographic and perspective projection method - `Matrix4.CreateOrthographic(...);` and `Matrix4.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(...);` There's also a lookAt method: `Matrix4.LookAt(...);`

The OpenTK bindings for OpenGL accept Matrix4 for methods like `GL.LoadMatrix()`, `GL.UniformMatrix4()`, etc.

Comment: Yes! I just discovered that recently during my research. Thanks! Seems almost a little funny to put those on the `Matrix4` close though... those matrices are not generic enough for applications outside of OpenGL so it seems like they should be apart of some GL class.... but no matter, they work.

Comment: Core OpenGL removed everything matrix-related and expects users to do their own matrix math. The reason why it's not part of the `OpenTK.Graphics` namespace is because the math classes are used for the OpenAL bindings and will definitely be used in the upcoming OpenCL bindings.

Comment: Ah...so they do have applications in audio and....whatever OpenCL is used for? Fair enough then !

Comment: OpenCL (Open Compute Language) uses the graphics card to run tasks typically done on the processor but that would benefit from parallelizing and vectorization, as a modern GPU has >500 cores with mostly instructions to deal with vectors.

Comment: I gathered that, but I'm not sure how "CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView" would be beneficial for such things.

Comment: Fair enough, the math classes are definitely skewed towards OpenGL. The OpenGL bindings have been around the longest.

Answer (score 0):

From [Ch4 of the OpenGL book](http://openglbook.com/the-book/chapter-4-entering-the-third-dimension/), `GLu.Perspective` is more or less equivalent to:

```
98  Matrix CreateProjectionMatrix(
99      float fovy,
100     float aspect_ratio,
101     float near_plane,
102     float far_plane
103 )
104 {
105     Matrix out = { { 0 } };
106  
107     const float
108         y_scale = Cotangent(DegreesToRadians(fovy / 2)),
109         x_scale = y_scale / aspect_ratio,
110         frustum_length = far_plane - near_plane;
111  
112     out.m[0] = x_scale;
113     out.m[5] = y_scale;
114     out.m[10] = -((far_plane + near_plane) / frustum_length);
115     out.m[11] = -1;
116     out.m[14] = -((2 * near_plane * far_plane) / frustum_length);
117  
118     return out;
119 }
```